# Error when cancel the showInputDialog

Tags: java, swing, input, joptionpane

I want to create a input dialog box when new record is created and save the user input as `input` into the file.

Here is the code :

```
String input = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Enter name :  ", "New Record!", 1);                //This to let user input name
    try
    {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Thanks for playing.", "Thanks", 1);            //Show this dialog after user input
        HighestScoreFile.HighestScoreFile(input, hours, minutes, seconds, click);                 //Store the data into a file, the `method` is in another class.
    }
    catch(IOException ex){}
```

When there is no user input or any input, the `OK` button work fine, but if I click the `cancel`button, it returns these errors :

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at HighestScoreFile.HighestScoreFile(HighestScoreFile.java:22)
    at MemoryGame$ButtonListener.actionPerformed(MemoryGame.java:329)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2018)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2341)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:402)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:259)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:252)
    at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6505)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3321)
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6270)
    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2229)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4861)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2287)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4687)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4832)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4492)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4422)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2273)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4687)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:707)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$000(EventQueue.java:101)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:666)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:664)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:87)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:680)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:678)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:677)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:211)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:128)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:117)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:113)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:90)
```

How can I solve it?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
String input = ....
if (input!=null) { ...
```

Comment: It may be of some use to mention that not all `JOptionPane.showInputDialog(...)` methods describe what is returned upon closing the dialog if the Cancel button was clicked. Only the method with the largest number of parameters claims to return `null` if Cancel was clicked.

Comment: @Timmos  Good point.  The Java Docs can be a little obtuse at times, and 'presume' knowledge that is not apparent to the user (us).  I can almost see the programmer as they had the source code open and were (forced to) write code comments.  It was 'obvious' to them than each shorter version, called the more operands version with `null` or standard defaults - so it never *occurred* to them to mention that in the docs..  I am pretty sure we can assume that, but it would be nice to see that explicitly documented.  Or at least `@see 'version this uses for more detail..'`.

Answer (score 8):

If the user clicks on "cancel", `input` will be null.

You should enter the `try` block only if the user clicks on "ok" or you should add an `if` to check if `input` is null before trying to use it!

Now, you can actually disable the cancel button with

```
JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Enter name :  ", "New Record!", JOptionPane.OK_OPTION);
```

or checking if the user clicked on cancel with

```
if (input == null){
    // Do something
} else {
    try {
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Thanks for playing.", "Thanks", 1);
    HighestScoreFile.HighestScoreFile(input, hours, minutes, seconds, click);
    } catch(IOException ex){}
}
```